# LayoutAnimation : how to not animate entering views?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm currently trying to animate a view change with `LayoutAnimation`.
Using this code :

```
LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
```

Produces :
[Video](http://dc700.4shared.com/img/HoHXdrGwba/aeee5a04/dlink__2Fdownload_2FHoHXdrGwba_3Fsbsr_3D82c07cccfe107831a804ac24185d613a996_26lgfp_3D1000_26dsid_3Dhljsk0.95956f7d12ca23587e0df5ab25e4352c/preview.mp4?cuid=1064120400&cupa=ee2135dae95f97e2dacec766f04b3dc1)

As you see, the "Filters" menu animates by fading in. I want it to not fadeIn (to appear at opacity 1 from start).

I tried doing :

```
LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
  duration: 200,
  create: {
    type: 'easeInEaseOut',
  },
  delete: {
    type: 'easeInEaseOut',
  },
  update: {
    type: 'easeInEaseOut',
  },
});
```

But I get the error : `Unsupported layout animation createConfig property (null)`. Is it possible to not animate created views with `LayoutAnimation` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply omit the `create` and `delete` keys:

```
  LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
    duration: 200,
    update: {
      type: 'easeInEaseOut'
    }
  });
```

The error `Unsupported layout animation createConfig property (null)` is caused by a missing required value called `property` on the create/delete animations.